# Randoop Maven Plugin

Tags: unit-testing, maven-plugin, test-coverage, randoop

Is there a maven plugin for Randoop, so we can generate tests for a framework (adding Randoop plugin in pom.xml) and use "mvn test" to see the number of generated tests and failures and also getting coverage of generated tests?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is such a plugin.

https://github.com/5aab/randoop-maven-plugin

It is a 3rd  party plugin, as can be seen by the fact that "Maven" follows that plugin name, whereas official plugins have "maven" in the front.

Answer (score 0):

Two Maven plugins for Randoop are:

- https://github.com/5aab/randoop-maven-plugin
- https://github.com/zaplatynski/randoop-maven-plugin

Neither one seems to be maintained currently (their last commits were in April 2018 and April 2017, respectively).
There is also https://github.com/hascode/randoop-maven-plugin which has not been updated since 2012.